# converting bash script to .bat

Tags: bash, batch-file

```
#!/bin/bash

function usage(){
cat <<EOF
USAGE: $0 [strategylist]

  valid strategies are:
    ALLD
    ALLC
    TitForTat
    JOSS
    WeightedRandom
    Tester
EOF
exit 1
}

[ -z $1 ] && usage

javac robsAgents/*.java robsAgents/behaviours/*.java

agentlist='leader:robsAgents.TournamentLeader'
agentlist=$agentlist";$1:robsAgents.Contestant"

while shift;
do
    agentlist=$agentlist";$1:robsAgents.Contestant"
done

java jade.Boot -gui -host 127.0.0.1 "$agentlist"
```

i have above bash script and have no access to a windows computer and i need to convert it to a .bat file, but don't even know how to do the shift and argument parsing

Comment: FYI .bat is not the same as "windows script".  Also - if you don't have a Windows computer, then why produce the script?  You'll need to test it, surely.

Comment: Agreed. Try to use VBScript, its far more powerful (and even uglier).

Comment: i had to make a java program and the teaching assistant wanted a .bat file to test my solution, and since i don't have windows i'm at a lost to be honest

Comment: take a look to: http://ant.apache.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to use [shift](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491002.aspx) in batch:

```
:Loop
if "%1"=="" goto End
  use %1 here
shift
goto Loop
:End
```

Answer (score 1):

Although giving this obvious answer tends to annoy people, it's really not bad advice and totally solves the bash-portability problem: ***install Cygwin*** on the TA's machine.

Yes, installing Cygwin is way overkill for many of the little problems posted. But the install is quick, easy, and online, and the installer gets *years* of small and large problems solved. It seems like a win to me.

My apologies to the Cygwin-suspicious.

Comment: i would like to tell him to do that, but he isn't that tech savvy, just good in agent programming